# Regular expression including spaces and newlines

Tags: javascript, html, regex

If I wanted to do a split on some text between `"/div>"` plus (either a new line or a space) plus `"<div id="`

how would i do this using regular expressions in JavaScript? I thought it would be:

```
"/div>" + "[' ']*[\r\n]" + "<div id"
```

Comment: Can you give a better example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression looks strangely like string concatenation.

Also, `[' ']*[\r\n]` matches zero or more spaces or `'` in between, followed by either `\r` or `\n`. What you really want is either a space, `\r`, or `\n`, which can be expressed using a character class (matches any single character within the `[` `]` brackets):

```
[ \r\n]
```

In general, for matching whitespace (which includes tabs, newlines, and spaces), you can just use the special `\s` pre-defined character class instead of defining your own.

Example:

```
var str = "/div> <div id";
var parts = str.split(/\s/, 1);    // [ '/div>', '<div id' ]
```

Comment: Shouldn't the backslash character be doubled inside a string?

Comment: What is the significance of the string concatenation? Javascript typically uses the '/' character to delimit a regex. Also, the string.split method that takes a regex, will remove the regex match from the original string when doing the splitting. What am I missing?

Comment: @Hans: Yes, if the regex is in a string and passed to the `RegExp` constructor; here, I've used a regular expression literal (`/.../`) to avoid this problem

Comment: @NerdFury: I was editing to remove the string concatenation as you commented (I was copying from OP and only just realized it made no sense). As for the split, the `div` parts in the regex made no sense, I wasn't thinking. Good catch ;-)

Comment: @Cameron So, now in your example, the parts array will look like this {"/div>", "<div", "id"} which is not what he wants either. I think he needs to clarify his intent better because this may not be the right solution.

Comment: @NerdFury: Hmm, you're right. The OP almost certainly doesn't want that! Editing again... I really shouldn't answer regex questions when I'm sleep deprived :-)